# $.ajax method is failing on Windows XP (IIS 5.1)

Tags: ajax, windows-xp

I have a JavaScript code that makes a ajax call to a method in my controller. Below is the code

```
function DisplayFullImage() {
    var model = {
        ChoosenColor: sendDesignerData,
        TotalDensity: TotalPixelFilled
    };

    var urls = '@Url.Action("GetColors","Designer")'
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urls,
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        success: function (data) { },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function (data) { alert("error"); }
    })
}
```

This function works on Windows 7 with FireFox V 26. But it fails on Windows XP with FireFox V 26. I am not sure why this ajax method fails only on Windows XP with `IIS 5.1` and I get "error" alert message when this method is called.

Comment: Use Firefox developer tool bar or firebug plug-in to see what the server is returning. HTTP response code and payload may have some clues about the error.

Comment: When i used Webdeveloper tools, i see that after $.ajax execution, the control is going to some method in Jquery1.7.1.min.js. It is failing there. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: I am getting "Http/1.1 404 Object Not found" error when i check the html(request.responseText). But i have my "GetColors" method in DesignerController.cs file. Not sure what is the issue. Stuck up baddly :(